# Goodman furnace - C Wire connection

Tags: wiring, thermostat, furnace, central-heating, transformer

I'm trying to connect the C wire in my Goodman furnace in order to install a new thermostat. I've read all the posts on this forum about this specific issue so my question is whether i'm in the right path or not.
Here are a couple pictures of my transformer and the R G W Y and C terminals.
[image: Transformer]
As you can see, on the lower left side of the transformer I have two blue wires and one wire connected to the chasis. From what I understood from other posts, one alternative is to use a piggyback connector to link it to the C terminal.

[image: Terminals]
I don't know if you can appreciate it on the picture but the C terminal is on the bottom and there's a blue wire connected to it that's also connected to the chasis.

So, to sum up my question is: do I have to use the piggyback connector or being both points connected to the chasis the only thing I have to do is connect the thermostat to that C terminal?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use that screw terminal for the C wire in the bottom picture.  I assume that the blue wire on the spade terminal goes to the 24v transformer?  It looks like the transformer has a red wire and a blue wire coming off it.  The red wire from the transformer is the "R" and the blue wire would then be the "C" wire.

Looks like an easy hookup - on some older units to have to hunt around more to find a good connection point.

Comment: Actually that blue wire is connected to the chasis as is also the dark cable that comes out of the 24v transformer, that's where I got kinda lost.

Comment: The “common” side of the transformer being attached to the chassis is pretty common.

Comment: But the fact that the blue wire from the C terminal is also connected to the chasis means I have 24v on the C terminal? Thanks

Comment: Yes, if you measure between red and blue, or red and the chassis, you should have around 24v.

Comment: Hi, I just wanted to let you know that it worked! Thanks for your help.